# Laravel and PHP - Condition in the SQL request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query

```
  $BaseUsers = DB::table('users', 'users.ustatus', '=', '1')
          ->join('user_infos', 'user_infos.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
          ->select('users.*', 'user_infos.add1', 'user_infos.add3')
          ->paginate(3);
```

It work fine. But i need insert condition "where" to search in result
i send $request from form. How insert condition to query?

In PHP it looks like this:

```
if($request['add_1'])
{
$insert1=" and add_1<>'' ";
}

if($request['add_2'])
{
$insert2=" and add_2<>'' ";
}
...

$sql=" SELECT users.*, user_infos.add1, user_infos.add3 FROM users JOIN user_infos where users.ustatus=1 and user_infos.user_id=users.id ".$insert1." ".$insert2."";
```

How can this be done on laravel in Controller? I mean - just insert the necessary condition insert1, insert2 ... into the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `where()` and `has()` to build your query

```
$query = DB::table('users');

if($request->has('age')) {
    $query->where('age', '>', $request->age);
}

$query = $query->get();
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: btw you don't need to reassign `$query` after the `where` call, it is returning itself not a new object

Answer (score 1):

All is simple ) I use when in query

```
$BaseUsers = DB::table('users', 'users.ustatus', '=', '1')
          ->join('user_infos', 'user_infos.user_id', '=', 'users.id')

          ->when($request->input('f_add3'), function ($query) {
                              return $query->where('user_infos.add3', '<>', '');
                          })


          ->select('users.*', 'user_infos.add1', 'user_infos.add3')
          ->paginate(3);
```